# erl VM - how to load my module on startup ( c(modulename) )

Tags: erlang, erl

I can run erl from my application and it must be turned on, I really don't want to make win32API Hook + sentMessage to run c(mymodulename), that's why I'm interesting if there some auto-load for modules or I can add it to erl properties ?

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`erl -s module_name` will call module_name:start ()

in module_name:start () you can call all what you want

Comment: I don't need to start, I need to load my functions so I can use them later ? Or maybe make simple application that will load my beams ?

Comment: start is just a function - you can use/call it without making application

Answer (score 2):

Generally, what you need is to use the OTP (Open Telecom Platform) features. You can define an [Application](http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html) and simplify any start-up procedure.

There's also a nice tool, [`rebar`](http://alancastro.org/2010/05/01/erlang-application-management-with-rebar.html) which will handle every aspect of application management from the start of your project to the deployment. It will generate Erlang/OTP configuration files, base application source files and start-up scripts.